# Spark 1.6: How do convert an RDD generated from a Scala jar to a pyspark RDD?

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create some POC code that demonstrates how a Scala function can be called from PySpark such that the result is a PySpark.RDD.

Here is the code on the Scala side:

```
object PySpark extends Logger {

    def getTestRDD(sc: SparkContext): RDD[Int] = {
        sc.parallelize(List.range(1, 10))
    }

}
```

and this is what I'm doing to access it on the PySpark side:

```
>>> foo = sc._jvm.com.clickfox.combinations.lab.PySpark
>>> jrdd = foo.getTestRDD(sc._jsc.sc())
>>> moo = RDD(jrdd, sc._jsc.sc())
>>> type(moo)
>>> <class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>
```

so far so good - what I get back appears to be an instance of PySpark.RDD. the problems arise when I attempt to use the RDD:

```
>>> moo.take(1)
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1267, in take
    totalParts = self.getNumPartitions()
  File "/usr/local/spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 356, in getNumPartitions
    return self._jrdd.partitions().size()
  File "/usr/local/spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 312, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o25.size. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method size([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I also tried passing in the PySpark context instead of the Java one to see what would happen:

```
>>> moo = RDD(jrdd, sc)
>>> moo.collect()
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/usr/local/spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 312, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o21.rdd. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method rdd([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

still no go. is there a way to convert, or at least access, the data inside the Java RDD from PySpark?

*EDIT* I'm aware that I can convert the RDD to an Array on the Java side of things and iterate through the resultant JavaArray object but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I get back appears to be an instance of PySpark.RDD.

Just because it is a valid PySpark RDD it doesn't mean the content can be can be understood by Python. What you pass is an RDD of Java objects. For internal conversions Spark uses to Pyrolite to re-serialize objects between Python and JVM.

This is an internal API, but you can:

```
from pyspark.ml.common import _java2py

rdd = _java2py(
    sc, sc._jvm.com.clickfox.combinations.lab.PySpark.getTestRDD(sc._jsc.sc()))
```

Note that this is approach is fairly limited and supports only basic types conversions.

You can also use replace `RDD` with `DataFrame`:

```scala
object PySpark {
  def getTestDataFrame(sqlContext: SQLContext): DataFrame = {
    sqlContext.range(1, 10)
  }
}
```

```py
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame

DataFrame(
   sc._jvm.com.clickfox.combinations.lab.PySpark.getTestDataFrame(
       sqlContext._jsqlContext),
   sqlContext)
```

Comment: had to change the package name to `from pyspark.ml.common import _java2py` to `from pyspark.mllib.common import _java2py` but other wise it worked perfectly -- t/y!!